# cannot apply css successfully 

Tags: css

```
body{
    background:#eff3f6;
  border: 1px solid #C3D4DB;
}
.content{margin-top:1px;
margin-right:200px;
margin-left:200px;
background:#fefefe;}
.box
{
    background:#fefefe;
    border: 1px solid #C3D4DB;
    border-top:1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
    color:#444;
    font:normal 12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    margin:0 auto 30px ;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I applied the content selector to the parent `<div>` class and box selector to the child `<div>` class. Now its applied correctly. But whenever the content exceeds about some amount the whole body content will be dis appeared. So which property I need to take care?

Comment: [Please show your code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/), also show your relevant html here. Remember: we're looking for [SSCCE (Short Self-Contained Correct/Compilable Examples)](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `overflow: hidden` or add in `height: auto` like the example below to expand the .box div to cover all of its contents.

```
.box {
    background:#fefefe;
    border: 1px solid #C3D4DB;
    border-top:1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
       -moz-border-radius:5px;
            border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
       -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
            box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
    color:#444;
    font:normal 12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    margin:0 auto 30px ;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: auto; /* This will expand the height of the container to contain all of its contents */
    }
```

Comment: ya thanks.. but giving `height:auto;` is not working ...i removed `overflow:hidden;` then my problem solved.